# putting styled divs next to each other

Tags: css, html, css-float

Im making a website at the moment but i want to have 4 cirlcles in it wich stand next to each other,
with a margin with about 50px between them. i can get one of the circles in the right position, but when I want to do more of them it wont show the circle.

My css is:

```
.webdesign-circle {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background: #0EB1E8;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 50px 0px 0px 70px;
    float: left;
}

.onderhoud-cirlce {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background: #0EB1E8;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 70px 0px 0px 150px;
    float: left;
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: I think you only had a `cirlce` typo :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    .wrapper {
      width: 600px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .circle {
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      border-radius: 100%;
      margin: 25px;
      background: #213;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .circle:first-child {
      margin-left: 0px;
    }
    .circle:last-child: {
      margin-right: 0px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="circle one"></div>
    <div class="circle two"></div>
    <div class="circle three"></div>
    <div class="circle four"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are meaning? You could use `margin-left` http://jsfiddle.net/wzv4gmft/7/

Comment: yes it is but when I use this in my sublime an look on the website it still only shows one circle

Comment: What HTML elements are you using ? div ? span ? other ?

+ you have a typo and I copied it in my example lol `.onderhoud-cirlce`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean something like this

**HTML**:

```
<div class="circle one"></div>  
<div class="circle two"></div> 
<div class="circle three"></div> 
<div class="circle four"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.circle {
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
border-radius: 100%;
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 50px;
}

.one {
background: #e6e6e6
}

.two {
background: #e6e6e6
}

.three {
background: #e6e6e6
}

.four {
background: #e6e6e6
}
```

You can change the background colour of each circle through the different divs (one, two, three, four and five)

Comment: hey thank you very much but its not excactly what im looking for, i want to get multiple circles next to each other with a margin of like 50 px between it.

Answer (score 0):

My attempt :)

**Edit** : you have a typo and I copied it in my example lol `.onderhoud-cirlce`

**Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/14f0vunh/

**HTML**

```
<div class="webdesign-circle"></div>
<div class="onderhoud-circle"></div>
<div class="test-circle"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
[class*=circle]
{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

[class*=circle] + [class*=circle]
{
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.webdesign-circle {
    background-color: blue;
}

.onderhoud-circle {
    background-color: red;
}

.test-circle {
    background-color: green;
}
```